# How to Visit the Node.js Server app on Ubuntu From other Computers

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed the Node.js on Ubuntu 12.4 and the server is running localy but how I can see the rendered page by server from other computers? Do I need to have an IP address? for this?

Comment: Well, where are the *other computers* compared to your server? Are they connected to the same LAN/router or are you wanting to make the application publicly-accessible over the Internet? And, how familiar are you with networking -- dealing with routers, firewalls, port forwarding, etc.?

Comment: FWIW the answer I posted below makes a lot of assumptions -- essentially that they are looking for the easiest case scenario: a simple home lan network where they just wanted to serve the site locally. @JonathanLonowski is right in that for any other situation, there are a lot more details to work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command ifconfig will tell you what your IP address is. Depending on the server you're running you may need to add the port number as well. From another computer on the local network you would go to:

```
http://your_ip_address_here:port_number
```